# Creating a local rhyme-dictionary in java

Tags: java, database, tagging

beginner programmer, having only taken an AP CS class.
For my final project, im trying to design a rhyme dictionary in java, where the user can both add rhymes to the database, and input a word to bring up all the words in the database that rhyme with the word.

It's been suggested that I use a tagging system, but all the tutorials and help on the subject have gone way over my head.
Before that, I had an idea to create and save arraylists to file that contain blocks of words that rhyme with each-other. I'm not quite sure how to design this either.

If anyone has any tips on how i should design this, or  if you want to offer a site to help me learn a concept that could help me out, I would be really grateful.

Comment: You can probably start by simply serializing a map like the one greedybuddha suggests to a file. Look up Java Serialization and ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really broad question in the sense that there are many good options.  Also this is an area with many advanced techniques.  But if you are looking for something easy because of your familiarity level here is an idea.

Use a Map of the rhyming terminal sound to a list of all the words that it rhymes with. `Map<String, List<Word>>`.

Example

```
public class Word{
    String terminalSound; // example "ime"
    String fullWord;
}

Map<String, List<String>> rhymes = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

// Given a word, find it's terminal sound
String terminalSound = findTerminalSound(word);
List<Word> rhymesWith = rhymes.get(terminalSound);
```

The most important thing still left would be to be able to find the terminal sound of a word. But once you have that, filling this Map with the words should be an easy process.